# If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, is it possible to have $p = k$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

My question is as is in the title:

> If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, is it possible to have $p = k$?

We [know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618035)
$$p = k \implies \sigma(p^k)/2 \text{ is not squarefree}$$
[and](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3998982) [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197182)
$$p = k \implies p \text{ is bounded.}$$

Alas, this is where we get stuck!

Comment: Conjecturally, the *Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture* predicts that $k=1$. If this conjecture is true, then it would disprove $p = k$.

Comment: Additionally, note that Chen and Luo proved that
$$\sigma(m^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \iff p \equiv k \pmod 8$$
and
$$\sigma(m^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \iff p \equiv (k + 4) \pmod 8.$$
This implies that, if $p = k$, then $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ is **untenable**.

Comment: This question seems to be very difficult.  From the existence of spoofs where the power on the spoof special prime can be nearly arbitrary, we know that there is no purely combinatorial restriction on $k$.  Some congruence restrictions (as you mention) can be determined on the cofactor $m$, but not enough to rule out the possibility that $p=k$.  An answer could only be found using primality in some essential way.

Comment: Thank you for your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463777/if-pk-m2-is-an-odd-perfect-number-with-special-prime-p-is-it-possible-to#comment1204215_463777), @PaceNielsen! I think that qualifies as an answer.